# Value returning as undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I need to get my latitude and longitude. Inside my function, it returns very well, but if i try to call the same this.latitude but out of function, it returns as undefined.

```
localizar() {

this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

  this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  // Here it returns
  console.log('teste: ', this.latitude, this.longitude);

})
// Here returns as undefined
console.log('lat: ', this.latitude, 'lng: ', this.longitude)
```

}

Comment: This is standard Promise behavior. You *have* the value inside the `.then` but you are not guaranteed to have it elsewhere without `await` or `.then` (or just wait long enough, but don't do that).

Comment: There is a way to get these value? Using await? Is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async localizar() {
  const position = await this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
  this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await features.

```
async localizar() {
    const position = await this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
    this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    // your logic here
}
```

More info about [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):